# how to store array of custom data object in android internal storage using kotlin file stream

Tags: android, kotlin

```
//THIS IS THE CUSTOM OBJECT CLASS  myLocation 
package com.hari.keralacovidtracker.Models

open class myLocation(val lat:String, val long:String) {
override fun toString(): String {
    return super.toString()
}
}

//I AM TRYING TO STORE LOCATION OBJECT IN INTERNAL STORAGE
//BELOW IS THE LOCATION LISTENER CODE

   lateinit var locarray:Array<myLocation>

   private val locationListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        val latitude= location.latitude.toString()
        val longitude= location.longitude.toString()
        val loc= object:myLocation(latitude,longitude){}
    }
    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
 }
```

I want to load this loc object to my apps internal storage and also don't know how to read the data from internal storage the new object is created every time the person change location and it need to be saved in internal storage and any way to access it efficiently?

Comment: Why a file stream? Google for SharedPreferences.

Comment: i don't understand can you make it more clearer??